# Vpn access when only http and https are available

Tags: https, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm trying to access my computer at the office from a library which allows only HTTP and HTTPS. The problem is that right now i can access the computer at the office by using remote desktop of windows. So i really need to use a VPN. Is it possible to do this simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a program that does the job. I don't know how secure it is exactly but it's display is much better than teamviewer.

[Columbus remote desktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/colrd/?source=directory). So basically i establish a vpn connection using network connect already configured by the network administrator of the network at the office. Then I just had to use the IP address of my computer at the office to connect.

Thanks and best wishes to you.